# python time series missing y axis label 'observed'

Tags: python, plot, time-series

I have the following dataset and try to plot the decomposition of the time series. The plot gives me Trend, Seasonal and Resid as Y labeling but the label for the first subplot 'observed' is missing. How can I add the label?

```
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose

df_event_decompose.head()

            NumberOfEvents
EventDate   
2011-12-31  96
2012-01-31  3989
2012-02-29  3979
2012-03-31  3861
2012-04-30  3963

result_add = seasonal_decompose(df_event_decompose['NumberOfEvents'], model='multiplicative',period=12, extrapolate_trend='freq')

plt.rcParams.update({'figure.figsize': (10,10)})
result_add.plot()
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add the 'Observed' y-axis label manually after plotting the DecomposeResult object like so:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose

sd_results = seasonal_decompose(data) 
fig = sd_results.plot()
```

Check the current y-axis labels:

```
fig.axes
```

which will return:

```
[<AxesSubplot:>,
 <AxesSubplot:ylabel='Trend'>,
 <AxesSubplot:ylabel='Seasonal'>,
 <AxesSubplot:ylabel='Resid'>]
```

Now, add axes labels for clarity.

```
fig.axes[0].set_ylabel('Observed') # Label 1st subplot's y-axis.
plt.xlabel('Year') # Add x-label for clarity.
```

You can check the fig.axes or the figure itsef to confirm the changes have been made:

```
[<AxesSubplot:ylabel='Observed'>,
 <AxesSubplot:ylabel='Trend'>,
 <AxesSubplot:ylabel='Seasonal'>,
 <AxesSubplot:xlabel='Year', ylabel='Resid'>]
```